# SQL Server - best approach for searching between two dates

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hello and thanks in advance for taking a look at this.

I have discovered an issue in 45 stored procedures that someone else wrote, she commented that the performance has slipped considerably.  I took a look and spotted the problem in about 5 minutes, ran a test and went from 60 seconds down to 4 seconds for one of the 45.  An index was not being used and a table scan was occurring on a table with 10 million + records.  This is using SQL Server 2005.

The table is an audit log and is queried by a  stored proc to pull the updt_tmstmp when a record has a specific value.  I changed the below block of code to use "NOT IN" vs 8 "product_code <> 'XX' " statements, changed the first datediff to use the indexed column updt_tmstmp and also added the check that the AUDIT_LOG.updt_tmstmp > @dtStartDate to achieve the peformance increase.  I just feel this could be implemented differently (more elegantly).  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on improvements.

```
WHERE
    PRODUCT.product_code NOT IN ('D01', 'D02', 'D03', 'D04', 'D05', 'D06', 'D07', 'D99') AND
AUDIT_LOG.updt_tmstmp >= @dtStartDate AND
    --Compares that the date entered is between the two date parameters
     (DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),AUDIT_LOG.updt_tmstmp)
      BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),@dtStartDate)
        AND DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),@dtEndDate)) 
    AND AUDIT_LOG.event_id = (SELECT MIN(AUDIT_LOG.event_id)
                FROM L_EVENT_LOG
                              WHERE AUDIT_LOG.transaction_id = PRODUCT.transaction_id AND                                                AUDIT_LOG.queue = 'AP')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison against `audit_log.updt_tmstmp` looks a bit strange.

```
AUDIT_LOG.updt_tmstmp >= @dtStartDate AND
    --Compares that the date entered is between the two date parameters
     (DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),AUDIT_LOG.updt_tmstmp)
      BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),@dtStartDate)
        AND DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),@dtEndDate))
```

I guess this would do the same.

```
audit_log.updt_tmstmp >= @dtStartDate and 
audit_log.updt_tmstmp < @dtEndDate
```

I have no idea what to do with the correlated sub query. It uses fields from the outer query in the where clause and does not use any fields from `l_event_log`. You should probably move the where clause to the main query instead.

Perhaps something like this.

```
where  product.product_code not in ( 'D01', 'D02', 'D03', 'D04',
                                     'D05', 'D06', 'D07', 'D99' ) and 
       audit_log.updt_tmstmp >= @dtStartDate and 
       audit_log.updt_tmstmp < @dtEndDate and
       audit_log.transaction_id = product.transaction_id and 
       audit_log.queue = 'AP' and
       l_event_log.event_id = (select min(audit_log.event_id)
                               from l_event_log)
```

Comment: Yes, the audit_log.updt_tmstmp does look strange, I agree.  The correlated sub query has a new edit done, I was playing with indexes in our dev environment and did not change the table name.  <oops!>

Answer (score 1):

I'd chip in with GETDATE() being called three times. Not sure if that gets optimised away, but worth putting that in a variable to start with to see if that helps.